# ReferenceField keeps showing loading bar on null value

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have following `List` component where `customerid` and `technicianid` are 
`ReferenceField`. Sometimes I have `technicianid` as `null`. So the UI keeps showing the loading bar (as shown in the image below).

**Question:**
How can I tell the ReferenceField to handle `null` and just show the empty string.

```
export const AppointmentList = (props) => (
    <List title="All Appointments" {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <ReferenceField source="customerid" reference="customers" label="Customer" >
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
            <DateField source="scheduleddt" label="Schedule Date" />
            <ReferenceField source="technicianid" reference="technicians" label="Technician" >
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <DateField source="createddatetime" label="Created" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the 'allowEmpty' attribute.

```js
export const AppointmentList = (props) => (
    <List title="All Appointments" {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <ReferenceField source="customerid" reference="customers" label="Customer" >
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
            <DateField source="scheduleddt" label="Schedule Date" />
            <ReferenceField source="technicianid" reference="technicians" label="Technician" allowEmpty>
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <DateField source="createddatetime" label="Created" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#referenceinput

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on it :)